# Koma's firstfoothpos length

Tags: koma-script, scrletter

This is a follow-up [to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579108/how-to-center-the-footer-in-koma).

koma's documentation reads, p. 228,

> \setplength{firstfoothpos}{length }
> A positive value of the firstfoothpos pseudo-length specifies the distance from the left edge
> of the paper to the letterhead page footer. If the value is greater than or equal to the papewidth, \paperwidth, the footer is centred horizontally on the letterhead page. But if the value
> is less than or equal to the negative width of the paper, the footer is placed flush with the lefedge of the typing area.
> The typical default for this value is \maxdimen, which is the maximum possible value for a
> length. This results in horizontal centring.

However the following:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\usekomavar{fromname}}
\setplength{firstfoothpos}{\maxdimen}
\setkomavar{fromname}{mycenteredname}


\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{%
            my text}
        \opening{bla}
        my other text
        \closing{best regards}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

that is, the footer *is not* centered.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your quote "footer" means a box of width `firstfootwidth` (default is `firstheadwidth`). This box is centered, but not its contents inside the box. You can visualize the footer by

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{foot}
```

in the preamble.

See the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\usekomavar{fromname}}
%\setplength{firstfoothpos}{\maxdimen}% default
\setkomavar{fromname}{mycenteredname}

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{foot}
\setplength{firstfootwidth}{5cm}% changes pseudolength firstfootwidth
    
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{my text}
  \opening{bla}
  my other text
  \closing{best regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```